# What's the best way to create a content type with multiple fields that link to an external URL?

Tags: entities, display-suite

I have a content type named "News Clip" that has four fields; Title, Description, Image, URL.

In my display, I want the Title and Image to link to the URL value.

Drupal has the concept of linking these fields to "Content", but that means the node itself.  I want them to link to the URL.

I use Display Suite for my other content types and would like to avoid having to use a field template.

Is this possible?  How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the fields to "hidden" under the "manage display" tab, and then print the fields however you like with a block view.

Just place that block view to appear on that content type only, and with a contextual filter to get content ID from URL.

You can also use the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module to replace the title from the content type, which you can then hide and display in the same block view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view "rewrite results" option.

Create a view and add all the fields you want to display. Then choose "exclude from display" option.

click on "rewrite results" section and select "Rewrite the output of this field" and write html code, use "SHOWREPLACEMENT PATTERNS".

Comment: I was really hoping to stick with Display Suite for display, but it's looking like I'll have to go back to using Views and fields.